# echarts not run in pixel6a with flutter webview

Tags: flutter, echarts, webview-flutter

I am developing an app with webview and i want put echarts 3d-earth in the web page.Most of android phones are run normal.but pixel6a cann't show the earch and it show a black background.How can i deal it .thanks.

Flutter Channel stable, 3.13.9,
webview_flutter: ^3.0.4